# Explain a proof from a paper: why the inequality $b<\|A\|$ is strict?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, proof-explanation

For $A\in\mathcal{L}(E)$, we consider
$$K=\{x\in E:\;\|x\|=1,\;\Re e\langle Ax,x\rangle\leq\frac{a}{2}\;\},$$
where $a$ is such that $\Re e( W_{0}(A))\geq a>0$, with
\begin{eqnarray*}
W_{0}(A)
&=&\{\alpha\in \mathbb{C}:\;\exists\,(z_n)\subset E\;\;\hbox{such that}\;\|z_n\|=1,\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\langle A z_n,z_n\rangle=\alpha,\\
&&\phantom{++++++++++}\;\hbox{and}\;\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\|Az_n\|= \|A\| \}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Set 
$$b:=\sup_{x\in K}\|Ax\|.$$

> Why
>   $$b<\|A\|?$$

This above strict inequality figures in the proof of the following theorem

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is $a$? If $a/2>\left\|A\right\|$ then $K$ can be all of the unit sphere and then $b=\left\|A\right\|$.

Comment: @Student It seems $K$ is a subset of the unit sphere of $E$, since for $x \in K$ we are insisting $||x|| = 1$. We know that $||A||$ is the maximum of $|Ax|$ over the entire unit sphere, so its maximum over a subset of the unit sphere, namely $K$, has  to be less than or equal to $||A||$.

Comment: Thank  you but my  problem  is why the  inequality is strict?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг But in the proof the inequality is strict.

Comment: @Student Use the other fact, namely that $\langle Tx,x \rangle$ is less than or equal to $\frac \tau 2$, and the fact that the maximum of this over the unit sphere is also $||A||$. Now look at relations between $\tau$ and $||A||$ as given in the definition of $W_0$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thank you but I don't understand what you mean. I hope that you write an answer

Comment: @Student Actually seeing an answer below had deflected my attention. But I will see what I can do.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that,
$$\eta  = \sup\{ \|Tx\| : x \in \mathfrak{S}\}$$

Suppose for contradiction that $\eta = \| T \|$.

It follows that all of the sequences $z_n \in \mathfrak{S}$ for which $\|Tz_n\| \to \eta$, also have the property that $\mathcal{Re}(Tz_n, z_n) < \tau / 2$. Let $\xi_n =(Tz_n, z_n) $ be such a sequence.

The complex part of $\xi_{n}$ is also bounded, since $\|z_n\| = 1$, and $T$ is a linear operator. By the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, there exists a convergent subsequence $\xi_{n_k}$ with a limit which we will call $\alpha$. We also have that $ \|Tz_{n_k}\| \to \eta $ as $k \to \infty$.

This is a contradiction since it would mean that $\mathcal{Re}(\alpha) \in \mathcal{Re}W_0(T)$, by the definition of $W_0(T)$; but $\mathcal{Re}(\alpha) \leq \frac{\tau}{2} < \tau $, and $ \tau $ is less than or equal to every element of $\mathcal{Re}W_0(T)$. It follows that $\eta \neq \|T\|$.

Since, 
$$\| T \| = \sup \{ \|Tx \| : \|x\| = 1 \}$$
and,
$$ \{ \|Tx\| : x \in \mathfrak{S}\} \subset \{ \|Tx \| : \|x\| = 1 \} $$
it follows that $\eta < \|T\|$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but $ \mathcal{Re}(Tz_n, z_n) \to \alpha $ doesn't means $(Tz_n, z_n) \to \alpha $

Comment: No that is true. It is a mistake, but $(Tz_n, z_n)$  does converge. If $\| Tz_n \|$ converges to a finite limit, then so does $z_n$ by the linearity of $T$ and continuity of $ \|\cdot \| $. We can then say that  $(Tz_n, z_n)$ converges to a number $\alpha$ since $(\cdot, \cdot) $ is continuous.

Comment: We have only $(Tz_n,z_n)$ is bounded and so has a convergent subsequence

Comment: I don't understand why $\alpha \in W_0(T)$?

Comment: $\alpha$ cannot be in $W_0(T)$ since it is strictly less that $\tau$. It is possible to prove that there exists a $z_n$ which converges. You are right that $(Tz_n,z_n)$ is bounded and therefore has a convergent subsequence. In fact, $z_n$ is also bounded and contains a convergent subsequence, $z_{n_k}$. The limit of $\| Tz_{n_k} \|$ is $\eta$, and say the limit of $ (Tz_{n_k}, z_{n_k}) $ is $ \alpha $, then $\alpha \in W_0(T)$ by the definition of $W_0$.

Comment: The problem why the limit of $(Tz_{n_k},z_{n_k})$ is $\alpha$ we have only the real part of  $(Tz_{n_k},z_{n_k})$ converges to $\alpha$

Comment: The $z_n$ are bounded because $z_n \in \mathfrak{S}$. However, this doesn't justify why there exists a convergent subsequence $z_{n_k}$. At least if the normed space has dimension $\infty$.

Comment: That is true. The Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem only holds for $\mathbb{R}^N$. If $\eta = \|T\|$, all of the sequences which converge to $\eta$ would also have the property that $(Tz_n, z_n) \leq \tau/2$, which would mean that $W_0(T)$ is empty.

Comment: The problem why the limit of $(Tz_{n_k},z_{n_k})$ is $\alpha$ we have only the real part of  $(Tz_{n_k},z_{n_k})$ converges to $\alpha$

Comment: It is only a matter of time...